# Hair particles flicker in and out on length influence animation

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I made a grassy patch with hair particles, I then made a cloud texture to control the length of the hair. I thought it would look cool keyframing the texture brightness to make the grass grow. But then i ran into this problem where the particles flicker in and out as the texture changes. i assume its to do with how it randomly paces particles on a gradient. I have no idea how to fix this, ive tried a couple of things like contrast up the map to make more of a sharp gradient but to no luck. Any idea how i can work on this ? Im Just including the files here instead of a bunch of screengrabs [Zip file with vid and blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An5mzigmb4SA4AJTKtaJt0qyspWu?e=aCJFjY) But here are 2 adjacent frames just to check it out

[image: Frame 1][image: Frame 2]

Answer (score 0):

Just as i post i figure it out. It was one particle instance texture that was still influencing density, If All of them influence only scale it works a treat.